# How do I draw a UML diagram with nested if statements?

Tags: uml

For example, I have a code like this:

```
if (morning) {
    if (beforeTenAM) {
        System.out.println("Go back to sleep"); }
    else { 
        System.out.println("Wake up!"); }
}
else {
    System.out.println("It's not morning anymore");
}
```

How can I represent this nested if else statement in a UML sequence diagram? Is it possible to do so? Or is a communication diagram better in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you *can* do that with a fragment in a SD like

[image]

As you can see it's geeting crowded soon and the code is more clear than that. Don't be tempted to start graphical programming. SDs are here to give an overview of collaborating objects. Leave the rest to coders and eventually provide some pseudo code.

An AD delivers a more business oriented aspect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities :

- an activity using decision nodes
- a sequence diagram using combined fragments